# How can I skip a stage if the agent is offline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my pipeline, I have a stage that checks to see if a specific computer (node) is offline.  If it is, I want to skip the next stage.  However, the next stage is set to use the offline agent, so it doesn't seem to be able to check the When clause.

Here's a simplified version of my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    environment {
        CONTINUERUN = true
    }

    stages {
        stage('Check Should Run') {
            agent any
            steps {
                script {
                    CONTINUERUN = false
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Skip this stage') {
            agent {
                label 'offlineAgent'
            }
            when {
                expression {
                    CONTINUERUN
                }
            }
            steps {
                //Do stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, the build just hangs at the 'Skip this stage' stage. I'm assuming, because the agent is offline.  How can I skip this stage, when the agent is known to be offline?

Comment: @RvdK If you read through the comments on the answer in that question, you'll see that the provided solution no longer works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to evaluate expression before allocating agent, you need to add *beforeAgent* directive to the *when* block.

Relevant part of [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#evaluating-when-before-entering-agent-in-a-stage):

> ### Evaluating `when` before entering `agent` in a `stage`
>
> By default, the `when` condition for a `stage` will be evaluated after entering the `agent` for that `stage`, if one is defined. However, this can be changed by specifying the `beforeAgent` option within the `when` block. If `beforeAgent` is set to true, the `when` condition will be evaluated first, and the `agent` will only be entered if the `when` condition evaluates to true.

Comment: Thank you @raspy!  I was just reading through the documentation myself, and came here to provide this exact answer.